# How to make rows duplicate in database if only one column is different in them . Such as DATE in below example

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID | USERID   |FORM                |data modification
---|----------|--------------------|-----------------
1  | 1115     |MATHS               |   2019-05-10
2  | 1115     |MATHS               |   2019-05-19
3  | 16161    |MATHS               |   2019-02-10
4  | 16161    |MATHS               |   2019-02-18
```

I have this table STUDENT in database . I want to write a query so that i can update STUDENTS Date of a subject FORM modification (date modification) . So that i get following table . There are multiple entries similar to this in table . Whenever a Form updates , i want to update dates for SAME form same STUDENT .  I am using this so that i can easily use DISTINCT . **Best solution would be to delete old entries and just keep the latest one** , but since i am learning PLSQL , triggers , dummy tables . I want to know , how can i achieve solution such that i get below output .

Output should be :-

```
ID | USERID   |FORM                |data modification
---|----------|--------------------|-----------------
1  | 1115     |MATHS               |   2019-05-19
2  | 1115     |MATHS               |   2019-05-19
3  | 16161    |MATHS               |   2019-02-18
4  | 16161    |MATHS               |   2019-02-18
```

I have tried using different SQL statements like :-
update

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  Your reference to PL/SQL suggests that it is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*, max(date) over (partition by userid) as latest_modification
from table t;
```

Comment: Great , i got the new column with the max dates  . Now how do i replace the values of date modified  with latest_modifications column .  I want to UPDATE the same table with max dates.

Comment: Thanks , I created a TEMP table to add the results from above statement . And replaced the date column with new one .

`WITH TEMP AS (select *, max(date) over (partition by userid) as latest_modification
from table students);
update STUDENTS set STUDENT.DATE=TEMP.DATE where STUDENT.userid=TEMP.userid and STUDENT.FORM=TEMP.FORM`